# After run .DbMigrator first time, but can't start my application , it has exception "tenant not found"

Tags: abp

When I direct download a template of abp NoTiered, the version is 3.1.2, then I run the .DbMigrator project, it run well, but then ,when i start .Web Application, It can't start with exception "**tenant not found**", then I check the "AbpTenants" Table in database, It is empty!!!

Comment: Where do you see the error It can't start with exception "tenant not found"

Comment: sorry,my mistake, your solution works well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your browser history (cookies) which stores any previous tenants.
The cookie is attempting to set your selected tenant, which is not configured in your new application.

Comment: Thanks tony, but I haven't opened the browser yet. I only open the database to see AbpTenants table after run .DbMigrator project，it is empty.